# I am getting the error while building the pipeline in jenkins , My build is getting failed

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, sonarqube-scan

```
Started by user Aditya
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Automated-Pipeline
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Automated-Pipeline/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Aditya-Kdm/CI-CD-Pipline.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Aditya-Kdm/CI-CD-Pipline.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.34.1'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/Aditya-Kdm/CI-CD-Pipline.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision c1ddaa6a7e07ad2346ece15a00be19e9da9a358b (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f c1ddaa6a7e07ad2346ece15a00be19e9da9a358b # timeout=10
Commit message: "Create test.txt"
 > git rev-list --no-walk c1ddaa6a7e07ad2346ece15a00be19e9da9a358b # timeout=10
[Automated-Pipeline] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Sonarqube-Scanner/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=http://3.111.52.250:9000 ******** -Dsonar.projectKey=Te-Website -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Automated-Pipeline
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Sonarqube-Scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 5.0.1.3006
INFO: Java 21.0.2 Private Build (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 6.2.0-1018-aws amd64
INFO: User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
ERROR: SonarQube server [http://3.111.52.250:9000] can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 30.443s
INFO: Final Memory: 4M/17M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:130)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:263)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:183)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:115)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:99)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
    ... 10 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

While running the Sonarqube pipeline in jenkins server I am getting the error

I'm running a Jenkins pipeline to perform SonarQube analysis on my project. However, the pipeline fails with the error message indicating that the SonarQube server cannot be reached at the specified URL (http://3.111.52.250:9000). This error seems to be causing the SonarScanner analysis to fail.

Actions Taken:

I've verified that the SonarQube server is up and running, and there are no connectivity issues with other services.
I've checked the Sonar-Qube server configuration and confirmed that it's accessible from other devices.

I am using :

Sonarqube Community Edition with version 10.4.1

SonarScanner version 5.0.1.3006

Java Version 21.

Thank You

Comment: Your exception tells nothing. Please paste the full stacktrace.

Comment: I have modified my question with more details